# reuse the function in oracle depending upon column passed

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a function which I want to work in different way depending upon the column passed.
I am calling that function in an UPDATE statement.
If I pass col A of a table then the case1 of the function should be implemented and if I pass col B then the case2 part of the function should be considered.

I can create two separate functions but I want to accomplish in one if its possible.

Eg:

```
create or replace Function test( para1 in varchar2)
v_para varchar2;
BEGIN
****If  paramater is coming from col A then perform 1st block Else perform 2nd block****
Begin

v_para := REGEXP_REPLACE (para1,'....');
v_para := .....
v_para := .....
Return varchar2
END
------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN
v_para := REGEXP_REPLACE(para1,'.....');
v_para := .....

Return varchar2
END

END;
```

Comment: Have you considered passing in a second argument, to specify what to do in the function?

Comment: Thats a good idea...I can pass second argument as NULL..So basically create a function with two arguments and when col1 is used call is like select test( col1, NULL) from dual ..If col2 is used then select test(NULL,col2) from dual;..Inside function i will use case if para1 is NULL THEN.... Else .....END

Comment: I guess @GordonLinoff's mean is to pass two arguments- the value of col and a string 'colA'or'colB'.e.g. In your sql before this function, select colA as para1,'colA' as para2 from table...

Comment: Thanks Gentlezerg..thats also good option to pass the column name as string.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to have two arguments, both defaulted to NULL, which you would pass by name, as in:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC(colA  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                      colB  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL) IS
BEGIN
  IF colA IS NOT NULL THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('colA=' || colA);  -- or do whatever
  END IF;

  IF colB IS NOT NULL THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('colB=' || colB);  -- or do whatever
  END IF;
END TEST_PROC;
```

Then when you call this procedure, pass the argument you want to use by name, as in:

```
DECLARE
  rowTest_table  TEST_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
    INTO rowTest_table
    FROM TEST_TABLE
    WHERE SOMETHING = SOMETHING_ELSE;

  TEST_PROC(colA => rowTest_table.A);

  TEST_PROC(colB => rowTest_table.B);
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a single function for this. If it's a matter of which element is passed in deciding which algorithm is used then this should be two functions.

I realise that there are ways of achieving what you want (I'd favour the extra parameter for which algorithm to run), but I think your aim here is fundamentally flawed.